# SSIS package is not terminating

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SSIS package which will execute a set of sql commands and some sps. there is one main sp in the package which will execute some sps in loop. But when i scheduled it as job in sql server, sps will be executed but it never comes out from the execution. It will stuck in that satage.

Answer (score 0):

I would do some serious debugging here.  It sounds like one of your stored procs either

**1) has an endless loop somewhere**
or
**2) there is a significant amount of blocking happening**